# Operator quits too early with no errors?

Tags: python, rendering, operator, collections

My goal is to look into a collection, and render each object seperatly. So it should turn on render visibility, render, then turn off render visibility. move to the next object and do the same for that one.

What is happening is the operator seems to stop when it gets through 2 objects when i know there are more objects in the collection.

I tried trouble shooting by running it without `bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport = True, write_still = True)`. I get every object printing to the screen. so i know that i should be running the render operator for each object but it seems to stop after 2 objects and even abort the `coll_render`  function.

Any help is appreciated. my code is below.

````
    import bpy
    import os
    
    def coll_render (*args):
        for obj in bpy.data.collections['Render'].all_objects:
        
            obj.hide_render = False
            print(obj.name, ': Revealed')
    
            file_name = obj.name + '.png'
            new_dir = os.path.join('mydir/', file_name)
            bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = new_dir
            print(new_dir)
    
            print('----- RENDERING ------')
            bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport = True, write_still = True)
    
            obj.hide_render = True
            print(obj.name, ': Consealed\n')
    
    
    class EE_OT_render_collection(bpy.types.Operator):
        """Render Collection"""
        bl_idname = 'wm.render_collection'
        bl_label = 'Render Collection'
        bl_options = {'REGISTER'}
        
        def execute(self, context):
            
        
            coll_render()
            
            print('Fishished')
            return {'FINISHED'}
    
    
    
    # Only needed if you want to add into a dynamic menu.
    def menu_func(self, context):
        self.layout.operator(EE_OT_render_collection.bl_idname, text="Render Collection")
    
    
    # Register and add to the view menu (required to also use F3 search "Hello World Operator" for quick access).
    
    
        
        
    classes = [
        EE_OT_render_collection,
    
    ]
    
    
    def register():
    
        for cls in classes:
            bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
            
        bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_rotate_canvas.append(menu_func)
    
    
    
    def unregister():
    
        for cls in classes:
            bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        register()
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Render all `MESH` objects in active collection

Use `bpy.app.handlers.render_complete` to check when rendering is complete

Turn off/on render visibility of objects in the collection one by one.
when render done, `render_slots` will change and do the next render, or you can change to save the image first.

```
import bpy

def when_render_done(dummy):
    self = ModalDrawOperator.SELF
    print(f"when_render_done: {self.job_ind + 1} / {self.job_len}")
    if self.job_ind == self.job_len - 1:
        print("render all done")
        self.all_done = True
        bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.remove(when_render_done)
        self.push_modal()
    else:
        self.objects[self.job_ind].hide_render = True
        self.job_ind += 1
        bpy.data.images["Render Result"].render_slots.active_index += 1 # or save to file first
        self.objects[self.job_ind].hide_render = False
        bpy.ops.render.render()

class ModalDrawOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.xx"
    bl_label = "XX"

    SELF = None

    def remove_timer(self):
        if self.TIMER is not None:
            bpy.context.window_manager.event_timer_remove(self.TIMER)
            self.TIMER = None

    def fin(self):
        self.remove_timer()
        self.__class__.SELF = None
        print("-- fin --")

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        cls = self.__class__
        if cls.SELF is not None:
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        self.collection = context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.collection
        self.objects = [obj for obj in self.collection.all_objects if obj.type == 'MESH']
        self.job_ind = 0
        self.job_len = len(self.objects)
        if self.job_len == 0:
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        self.all_done = False
        self.TIMER = None

        for obj in self.objects:
            print(obj.name)
            obj.hide_render = True
        self.objects[0].hide_render = False

        bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(when_render_done)
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        cls.SELF = self
        bpy.data.images["Render Result"].render_slots.active_index = 0
        print("The interface will be locked, please wait for finish")
        bpy.ops.render.render()
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        self.remove_timer()

        if self.all_done:
            self.fin()
            return {'FINISHED'}
        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def push_modal(self):
        if self.TIMER is None:
            self.TIMER = bpy.context.window_manager.event_timer_add(0)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalDrawOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalDrawOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

##### After run the script, you can run the operator by search menu

[image]